# Why/how does recursive IO work?

Tags: haskell

Haskell IO is often explained in terms of the entire program being a pure function (`main`) that returns an IO value (often described as an imperative IO program), which is then executed by the runtime.

This mental model works fine for simple examples, but fell over for me as soon as I saw a recursive `main` in [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output). For example:

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  main
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
main = getLine >>= putStrLn >> main
```

Since `main` never terminates, it never actually returns an IO value, yet the program endlessly reads and echoes back lines just fine - so the simple explanation above doesn't quite work. Am I missing something simple or is there a more complete explanation (or is it 'simply' compiler magic) ?

Comment: Like everything else in Haskell, the `IO` value is not strict and therefore is evaluated only as needed.

Comment: All types -- including `IO ()` -- have an extra value called [bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom). So `main` is technically "returning" an `IO ()`; it's just that it's returning the most boring `IO ()`: ⊥. Haskell can never evaluate the "whole" `main`, but due to non-strictness it can try.

Comment: If you think you're confused now, just wait till you learn about `fixIO::(a->IO a)->IO a`.

Comment: @IanHenry: At the top level it's strict, but the subexpressions are not.  So I guess "WHNF" would be a better way to say it?

Comment: @IanHenry, `main` *is* an `IO ()` which means that it *returns*  a `()`. The `()` it returns is ⊥, which is no more boring than the only other value of that type, namely `()`. This particular ⊥, however, can never be reached, no matter what. It's similar in that regard to the one that occurs in the list `[1::Integer ..] ++ undefined`.

Comment: @dfeuer a pretty important distinction that makes this make a lot more sense to me, thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, `main` is a *value* of type `IO ()` rather than a function. You can think of it as a sequence of `IO a` values:

```
main = getLine >>= putStrLn >> main
```

This makes it a recursive value, not unlike infinite lists:

```
foo = 1 : 2 : foo
```

We can return a value like this without needing to evaluate the whole thing. In fact, it's a reasonably common idiom.

`foo` *will* loop forever if you try to use the whole thing. But that's true of `main` too: unless you use some external method to break out of it, it will never stop looping! But you can start getting elements out of `foo`, or executing parts of `main`, without evaluating all of it.

Comment: You may want to mention that for `IO`, the `>>=` operation is strict in its left operand, but lazy in its right operand. It needs to know what to do first, but it doesn't need to know how to figure out what comes next until it's done the first thing.

Answer (score 8):

The value `main` denotes is an infinite program:

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  ...
```

But it's *represented* in memory as a recursive structure that references itself. That representation is finite, unless someone tries to unfold the entire thing to get a non-recursive representation of the entire program - *that* would never finish.

But just as you can probably figure out how to start executing the infinite program I wrote above without waiting for me to tell you "all" of it, so can Haskell's runtime system figure out how to execute `main` without unfolding the recursion up-front.

Haskell's lazy evaluation is actually interleaved with the runtime system's execution of the `main` IO program, so this works even for a function that returns an `IO` action which recursively invokes the function, like:

```
main = foo 1

foo :: Integer -> IO ()
foo x = do
  print x
  foo (x + 1)
```

Here `foo 1` is not a recursive *value* (it contains `foo 2`, not `foo 1`), but it's still an infinite program. However this works just fine, because the program denoted by `foo 1` is only generated lazily on-demand; it can be produced as the runtime system's execution of `main` goes along.

By default Haskell's laziness means that nothing is evaluated until it's needed, and then only "just enough" to get past the current block. Ultimately the source of all the "need" in "until it's needed" comes from the runtime system needing to know what the next step in the `main` program is so it can execute it. But it's only ever the *next* step; the rest of the program after that can remain unevaluated until after the next step has been fully executed. So infininte programs can be executed and do useful work so long as it's always only a finite amount of work to generate "one more step".