# How infinite loop with IO work in haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

In haskell, all the IO code that we write is just an action (many suggest to think it as a script being generated). It is the main method that finally executes them (execute the constructed script). So how does the following program work ? `infi` function will never return. So why does the string get printed infinitely ?

```
infi = 
    do
     print "hello"
     infi

main = 
    do
     infi
```

Comment: Why does your program need to halt to perform any actions? This isn't unique to haskell in that regard. I can write infinite for loops in any language and have them print on each iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why/how does recursive IO work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203214/why-how-does-recursive-io-work)

Comment: @jkeuhlen But in those other languages you're printing via side-effects - that's trivial. The OP's question is how any of the constructed `IO` value can be executed if the function constructing that IO value never returns (and the answer to that is laziness). That question isn't really applicable to other languages.

Comment: @sepp2k Fair enough, I missed that distinction from the question. I'll update my answer to deal with laziness more as well.

Comment: `infi` is not a function. Also, Haskell functions don't "return".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding as to how Haskell actually implements IO. There is plenty of other literature on the subject and several other answers on this site that deal with it, so I'll focus on your specific example rather than the general.

```
infi = 
  do
   print "hello"
   infi

main = 
  do
    infi
```

First off, you can simplify your main action (It doesn't need to have a `do`):

```
main = infi
```

In haskell, "return" is not the same as an imperative "return". It simply means injection into a monadic action, i.e. `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. So let's talk about what things are evaluated here, not when things return.

All your `main` function does is call the value `infi` which is of type `infi :: IO ()`. Since `infi` is an `IO` action, it can perform prints. Like any other value, it can also reference other values (in this case, it is recursive so it calls itself). Without a base case, infi will continue to perform the following sequence (just like it's laid out in your `do` block!):

1. print "hello" to STDOUT
2. evaluate the value infi

   1. print "hello" to STDOUT
   2. evalute the value infi
      ...
      The stack continues forever, since there is no base case in the recursion.

The main reason this can work is because of Haskell's lazy evaluation. Haskell never actually computes values until you need it. That's why you can do pure actions with infinite lists as well:

```
let x = [1..] -- x is an infinite list. If you told haskell to print every element, it would run forever since it would evaluate the whole thing. 
let y = x !! 3 -- y = 2. This is not infinite because you are only evaluating the first three elements, instead of the whole value.
```

The same is true of your infinite value `infi`. Haskell can create a "run-time-script" that contains the infinite actions because the *value* of infi has a finite representation (its name), but it evaluates infinitely because it has no base case.

Comment: Hmm. Actually many blogs mention that when we write print "hello", it returns an action of printing the hello string. The print as such doesn't happen. It's the main that then evaluates the action to print it

Comment: @FaizHalde I added a little extra to explain the laziness. Does that help more?

Comment: @FaizHalde That is correct (mostly). And `do putStrLn 'hello'` `infi` doesn't "call" `infi`. It returns an action of printing the hello string followed by "calling" `infi`.

Answer (score 3):

`infi` is essentially an infinite stream of the same `IO` action, connected with monadic sequencing (`>>`) instead of cons (`:`):

```
fives = 5                :  fives
infi  = putStrLn "hello" >> infi
```

In fact, we could abstract out the monadic bind using a list of actions `infi'`:

```
infi' :: [IO ()]
infi' = putStrLn "hello" : infi'
```

Then recover `infi` with `sequence_`, which can be implemented as `foldr (>>) (return ())`.

```
infi = sequence_ infi'
infi = (foldr (>>) (return ()) infi')
infi = putStrLn "hello" >> (foldr (>>) (return ()) infi')
infi = putStrLn "hello" >> (putStrLn "hello" >> (foldr (>>) (return ()) infi'))
infi = putStrLn "hello" >> (putStrLn "hello" >> (putStrLn "hello" >> ...))
```

Storing the actions in a stream like this also lets you manipulate them as first-class values:

```
> sequence_ (take 3 infi')
hello
hello
hello
```

When the Haskell runtime executes your `main` action, it evaluates `infi`, finds a `>>` expression, evaluates its left-hand argument to produce the action `putStrLn "hello"`, *executes* that action, then proceeds to the right-hand argument—which happens to be `infi` again. Evaluation is lazily driven by the internal pattern matching in the `Monad` instance for `IO`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to the program

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

The above is recursive, yes. It calls itself infinitely many times, yes. But it *does* return. It returns an infinite list. By comparison,

```
noList = noList
```

will loop forever without ever returning a list. (Actually, the GHC runtime detect this and throws an exception, but this is irrelevant for the discussion.)

Similarly,

```
printOnes = print 1 >> printOnes
-- or, equivalently
printOnes = do
   print 1
   printOnes
```

builds an IO action which will print `1` forever, even if it does recurse infinitely many times. Instead,

```
noPrint = noPrint
```

would loop forever and never return an IO action.

Answer (score -1):

Because infi is set to recursively call its self. The 'return' that is expected from main will never be met, as the first call to infi will never return.

```
# The first call to infi will never return as the calls to infi
# will just continue to add more calls to the stack, until you exceed
# the size :)

main ->
  infi ->
    infi ->
      infi -> ..
```

Comment: This is not correct. Infi will be evaluated endlessly.

Comment: That's exactly what I just said

Comment: @user3206627 No, you said it would never _return_. Since Haskell is lazy, `infi` does return, the problem is that its _evaluation_ takes forever.

Comment: Ah, didn't pay attention to the language. I did some reading about Haskell, and I'm curious about one thing -- while the semantics of 'return' and 'evaluate' are different, what is it conceptually that makes this scenario any different than in a non-evaled language? We are still ending up with a recursive action.

Comment: @user3206627. Lazy evaluation is the difference.

Comment: Lazy evaluation has no bearing over the concept of recursion in this situation. Even in your answer below you don't make the connection, as you say 'but it evaluates infinitely because it has no base case'. Verbiage aside, the concept of that is no different than the concept I outlined above.

Comment: @user3206627 Maybe read through the question I flagged as a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203214/why-how-does-recursive-io-work It has better answers than the one I wrote. I'm only a year into learning Haskell so I try to teach what I can, but my explanations may not be the most clear yet.

Comment: @Alec I would say that since Haskell is lazy, "`infi` does return" is a statement that makes no sense.