# Haskell: ok to recursively call main?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I've seen plenty of examples where `main` calls a helper function that calls itself recursively, e.g.

```
main = loop
  where
    loop = do
      putStrLn "I'm in a loop"
      loop
```

I have never seen a case where `main` calls itself recursively, e.g.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "I'm in a loop"
  main
```

It seems to work fine though, which leaves me wondering why I've never seen it. Is it considered non-idiomatic? Does it change something about the compiled program?

Comment: I expect it's just convention, and perhaps it's more readable. Recursively calling `main` is surprising, simply for how uncommon it is, but recursively calling a function called `loop` makes it clear what's going on. There may be more concrete reasons too, though.

Comment: For readability I prefer `forever $ do` over `f = ... >> f`.  This is as applicable to `main` as any other procedure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's perfectly fine, but it's pretty uncommon that every part of your program is repeated indefinitely. Usually you have some one-time setup or something, and then you enter into a loop to execute the remainder; or you have some cleanup to do after the main loop finishes. In that case you can't call `main` again, because it would do the one-time setup (or cleanup) every time. If you have no one-time setup, feel free to have `main` call itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since last call optimizations are a regular thing in Haskell, yes, that's completely fine. [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) includes some examples using this kind of recursion. Also, this [StackOverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203214/why-how-does-recursive-io-work) digs a little deeper in this topic.